# Mysql left join fails to returns all values from first table

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I've two tables named `table1` and `table2`. `table2` may have elements from `table1`. I'd like to show all the results from `table2` with the price if available in `table1` and with `status` 1. If no product matches in `table1` and also `status` is 0, need to return price as 0.

`table1`

```
id  pname       item_code   price   status

1   product1    abcd        200       1
2   product2    pqrs        500       1
3   product3    wxyz        425       1
4   product5    mnop        100       0
```

and `table2` as follows

```
id  item_code   

10  efgh
11  abcd
12  pqrs
13  mnop
```

I have tried following query

```
SELECT `t2`.`id`, `t2`.`item_code`, `t1`.`price`,`t1`.`pname`, COUNT(t2.item_code) AS sellers FROM (`table2` as t2) LEFT JOIN `table1` as t1 ON `t1`.`item_code` = `t2`.`item_code` WHERE `t1`.`status` = 1 GROUP BY `t2`.`item_code`
```

but it returns common values in table1 and table2 with status 1, but I need  all records from `table2` with price as 0 if nothing match in `table1` or `status` 0 in `table1`.

Expected output

```
id  item_code   price

10  efgh        0
11  abcd        200
12  pqrs        500
13  mnop        0
```

Any help please.

Thanks,

Comment: the where condition `WHERE t1.status = 1` makes it an `inner join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your current query which is having `count` and `group by` however you can do as below

```
select
t2.id,
t2.item_code,
case 
  when t1.status = 1 then t1.price
  else 0
end as price
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 on t1.item_code = t2.item_code
```

Now note that if `table1` has multiple matching values from `table2` in that case we may need grouping data.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
   SELECT `t2`.`id`, `t2`.`item_code`, `t1`.`price`,`t1`.`pname`, COUNT(t2.item_code) AS sellers FROM (`table2` as t2) LEFT JOIN (select * from table1 where status = 1)t1 ON `t1`.`item_code` = `t2`.`item_code`  GROUP BY `t2`.`item_code`
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the part of the WHERE clause that checks the left joined table to the ON clause

```
SELECT `t2`.`id`, `t2`.`item_code`, COALESCE(`t1`.`price`, 0),`t1`.`pname`, COUNT(t2.item_code) AS sellers 
FROM (`table2` as t2) 
LEFT JOIN `table1` as t1 
ON `t1`.`item_code` = `t2`.`item_code` 
AND`t1`.`status` = 1 
GROUP BY `t2`.`item_code`
```